# Get historical financial ratios in R?

Tags: r, quantmod

Hi using a fabulous package call quantmod. Is there way to get historical financial ratios, say PE or PEG ratio?  I tried doing.

```
getSymbols(c("AAPL"),what=yahooQF("PEG Ratio"))
AA = AAPL['2013-09-07::2013-10-20']
print (AA)
```

But this only prints:

```
AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2013-09-09    505.00    507.92   503.48     506.17    12167400        506.17
2013-09-10    506.20    507.45   489.50     494.64    26542700        494.64
....
```

Not sure if possible, but thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [qmao](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1113) package on R-Forge has some of this this -- see for example [the getEarnings()](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/qmao/R/getEarnings.R?view=markup&root=twsinstrument) function.